# JDBC Connection Pool / JDBC resource

Tags: java, tomcat

I am a beginner working on a project in Netbeans and using Glasshfish, but I have to deploy on TOMCAT on Elastic BeanStalk.  I don't know anything about tomcat.  To connect to my database, I use Entity Classes and a named connection jdbc/whatever (I hear this is called a JDNI name) in my persistence.xml.

On the Glassfish server bundled with Netbeans, I added a Connection pool and a JDBC resource.  This was done with a GUI.  It was super simple.  Create the JDBC connection pool after you stuffed the right driver in the right folder by pointing to the location of server/password/etc.  Then point the jdbc resource at the pool.

Now I need to do this with TOMCAT and XML.  I have no idea what I am doing...

1. How do I create a connection pool which all my applications can reach?
2. How do I then get JNDI? set up that persistence.xml can reference and make the magic db stuff happen?
3. How do I then set up a jdbc authentication realm based on this database?

It was magic in Glassfish is it was so GUI.  But I don't have a GUI for TOMCAT.

I am using spring.

Comment: not sure if you are servlets. if so, you can servletContext, to get your connection pool started?

Comment: @user3502355 Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes I am using spring.  No servlets.  Really just want to the XML syntax to pull this off.

Comment: Get the web admin package and there is a GUI for tomcat.

Comment: Or, use DI and inject a connection.

Comment: elliot - only problem is the web package is deleted by elastic beanstalk every time you reboot the darn thing.  That is because I am thinking the darned thing is clearing my webapps folder first.  I really just want the XML.

Comment: Also - no experience with DI and "injecting" a connection.  Is this something I can code?  In my computer science classes the kids doing injecting were usually not still in school.

Comment: So - Still not figuring it out.  I am not finding a real admin APP for TOMCAT 7 anywhere.  There appear to have been one at one point at mysite.com:8080/admin but that is gone now.  All I can find is mysite.com/manager which is sparse at best.

There has to be some way to get a JDBC pool/JNDI and a realm in there in an easy way.